# Need help powering a raspberry pi thermostat using 24v power from the unit. I have it working plugged in usb

Tags: wiring

I have a raspberry pi thermostat that is plugged in through USB. Dealing with this voltage I don't want to "try and see what happens". My current setup is the Pi is powering the relay module through VCC on the module. What I want to do is remove the ac adapter and power the whole thing from the red power wire out of the wall.

Because no one wants a thermostat with a wire running down the wall. So any help would be greatly appreciated. I am also open to using any board arduino, pi or whatever. Currently targeting final build with pi zero W.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Kaufman, Well, you can do something like this: (1) Use 24V DC wall wart to get 24V DC power near to your Rpi and 24V thermostat. (2) Use to 7V to 35V DC to 5V DC 3A step down voltage regulator to supply power for both Rpi and 5V relay (Don't get 5V power from Rpi 40 pin header's pint 2, 4 5V power rail, overloading Rpi!).

Comment: what is a raspberry pi thermostat?

Comment: @tlfong01 you should have made it an answer. i would have accepted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jonathan Kaufman, Thank you very much for your kindness.  So I have made an answer.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Answer***

You can do something like this:

> (1) Use 24V DC wall wart to get 24V DC power near to your Rpi and 24V
>   thermostat,
>
> (2) Use to 7V to 35V DC to 5V DC 3A step down voltage regulator to
>   supply power for both Rpi and 5V relay.

*Note*

Don't get 5V power from Rpi 40 pin header's 5V power rail (Pins 2, 4), overloading Rpi!).

---

*End of answer*